# History repeats itself

Tags: psychology

People say “History repeats itself”, more often when injustice, human relationships, phenomena fall under the same pattern we argue over this. But why don't people accept things so easily when something goes wrong for their actions? Is there any cure science and religion have over this? Intellectuals lose their arguments over their ego but fail to accept it. Is this human behavior when we have ethical codes but still under circumstances we don't follow them often?

Comment: Downvoted: I don't think this question is appropriate for this forum, and it's not entirely clear what is being asked.

Comment: In the West there is some acknowledgement of this through Schopenhauer, Nietzsche, Heidegger and Foucault: the will to power. Heidegger says only a god can save us in the end. But as Allan Megill very wisely surmised from the material cited: we cannot (must not) will the god because this would be reinfected with will to power. If we can have a god who can save us, such a god must arise organically.

Comment: So when our present absolute (current capitalism, money) is in direct opposition to life, time is of the essense, but we are in a bind since we can't will the god. You get some idea why the late Heidegger was so panicked by technology.

Comment: @Gordon impressive comment, but many times or most of the time people with intellectual thoughts and wise words fail in action, philosophers,musicians are wise souls but most of them fall into liberal or communism when we see wide spectrum of life as politics is somehow ugly in the sense but there other side looks more evil but still situation demands too, capitalism is one driving force indeed.

Comment: Dostoyevsky defined man as the "ungrateful biped," and that's a big part of our problem. We fail to thank God for His blessings and live our lives according to the love that He exemplified.

Comment: @nooneperfect - What is wrong in falling "into liberal[ism] or communism"?

Comment: Nothing, everyone has their way to accept thoughts, & communicate. Its just self observation nothing else to provoke political difference

Comment: Dostoyevsky is certainly a good one to read. Anyway, mankind seems to like to learn it's lessons the hard way, and we are set to learn soon enough just how hard it can be.

Comment: @nooneperfect maybe another option is the Shin Buddhism and say the the nembutsu, if you are familiar with this group.

Comment: @Gordon know the Buddhism but not talking any particular religion, every group, ethnicity has violence and peace so may be thats the way life works.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the problems that we see "repeat" were not solved to begin with.  These are difficult intractable issues like balancing liberty of the individual with the needs of society to be protected from the individual.  Justice for the individual or minority as contrasted with justice for society.  Not to mention Justice vs. mercy, or beauty vs. utility and so on.  It is often not so much that history is repeated, as that the issues remain because there are no easy, obvious answers.  We wrestle with such questions in philosophy and hope to improve.

Comment: Thanks for comment, thats reasonable observation and great point of view.